# process.env.INIT_CWD UNDEFINED

Tags: node.js, environment-variables

I am using INIT_CWD to get a local file for a test. This works with my colleagues in windows, but on my Ubuntu it is undefined.

This is my .env file:

```
NODE_ENV=development

# Http-server
HTTP_PORT=3000

# Database
DB_NAME=DbName
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=27017

# Token
TOKEN_SECRET='REDACTED'
```

I have tried using:
    export NODE_ENV=development

Comment: vi ~/.bash_profile then insert NODE_ENV=development and save

Comment: This does not work, I still have the error

Comment: you would need to either run "source ~/.bash_profile" or restart the shell/terminal/session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was my Node version.
I was on version 8

and now I am on 10.16.3

And now it works.